# Bootstrap row-fluid in a iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a bootstrap modal window in which I have placed an iframe.

Now when I try make use of the row-fluid bootstrap class all the rows sit on top of each other.

This only occurs in firefox not in google chrome.

Suggestions Please.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" >
<div id="myModalBody" class="modal-body">
    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'></button>
    <h3 id='myModalLabel'>Profile</h3>
    <iframe id='profile'  width='99.5%' height='94%' style='border-width: 0;' scrolling='no'></iframe>
</div>



 function setprofile(id)
{
    profileid=id;

    $('#profile').attr('src','profile.php?profileid=" + profileid + "');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and figured out that I've used the wrong elements. Here is my question and a solution for it [Bootstrap code in an iframe is not rendered properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947212/bootstrap-code-in-an-iframe-is-not-rendered-properly)