# Bootstrap code in an iframe is not rendered properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is simple html page with an iframe. Inside this iframe are some fluid rows. The problem is now that the content in the iframe is stacked but it should be on the same row. There is enough space for "label" and "main content" to be on the same line.

Here is the code of the main page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" dir="ltr" >
<head>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">
<iframe src="frame.html" width="500px"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code of the iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" dir="ltr" >
<head>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span6">label</div>
<div class="span6">main content</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span6">label 1</div>
<div class="span6">main content 1</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**The result is now:**
label
main content
label 1
main content 1

**instead of**
label     main content
label 1   main content 1

Does somebody know how can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Width of your iframe is 500px, and if you are using Twitter Bootstrap css for responsive layout, media queries will break your layout for small screens. You can use current markup, but remove Twitter Bootstrap responsive CSS.

Below is example with [`bootstrap-responsive.css`](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css)

http://jsfiddle.net/ebrPt/ (try to decrease width)

And here is example without responsive css

http://jsfiddle.net/ebrPt/1/ (try to decrease width)

Comment: Why removing responsive layout? I don't see any difference in your jsfiddles. Did you try out my example on a web server? What I guess is that bootstrap is determining wrongly the width of the iframe, instead of takes the screen width.

Comment: You don't see any difference in my jsfiddles? Strange... Screen width of your iframe is 500px, so Bootstrap breaks your layout inside iframe for small screen sizes.

Comment: Should bootstrap not consider the width of the space within the iframe (500px) instead of the screen size.

Comment: The widht of th iframe **is** screen size for the iframe.

Comment: But then it should not be stacked.

Comment: How can then a span1 have a width of 460px (tested with chrome)?

Comment: That is because responsive css for Bootstrap have media queries. When screen size get width smaller than 780px, every `.span` class in Bootstrap will get width of 100%, and gets stacked below previous one.

Comment: Ah ok what you suggest then as alternative? I've discovered the same behavior here http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html

Comment: From TB official docs: `With the responsive CSS file added, the grid adapts to be 724px and 1170px wide depending on your viewport. Below 767px viewports, the columns become fluid and stack vertically`... So, solution is - don't use responsive CSS inside iframe, as I said in beginning. :) Inslude just [THIS CSS](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css) inside iframe

Answer (score 0):

Finally I ended up overriding some media tags of bootstrap when I'm in an iframe

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
        float: left !important;
        width: 49% !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
        float: none !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
    }
}
```